# Assistance with SQL query to return records for duplicated object with the latest timestamp

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to output results against a table which contains a specific value and have it only reference the latest timestampe

Below example is the SQL query I am running -

```
SELECT id, componentNameId, attrName, attrVal, created 
FROM APP_SubClientProp
WHERE attrName = 'sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive' AND attrVal = 1
ORDER BY componentName
```

---

Output will show the following as a result -

```
id    componentNameId attrName                          attrVal   created
46397     310         sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive    1      1534884250
46402     310         sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive    1      1534885567
46404     310         sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive    1      1534887691
36458    1141         sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive    1      1530825395
```

---

Question is.... how can I outline the results to only show the latest timestamp? I have attempted using the `MAX` attribute with the created column, but it only presents the latest row shown against the `sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive` attribute

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It won't let me comment yet to ask questions. 
Is this not what you want?:

```
SELECT max(created)
FROM APP_SubClientProp
WHERE attrName = 'sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive' AND attrVal = 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT id, componentNameId, attrName, attrVal, created 
FROM APP_SubClientProp app_sub
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT max(created) max_dt
FROM APP_SubClientProp
WHERE attrName = 'sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive' AND attrVal = 1)tb2
on tb2.max_dt on app_sub.created
WHERE tb2.max_dt = app_sub.created
```

Comment: Chad - That is the exact problem I keep encountering here. It only shows the latest created timestamp. However, there is more than 1 componentNameId value and I would ideally like to group them together and show all of the componentNameId values with the latest created timestamp for anything that contains the 'sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive' value. This is what I'm having trouble figuring out

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `GROUP BY` clause?

```
SELECT id, componentNameId, attrName, attrVal, max(created)
FROM APP_SubClientProp
WHERE attrName = 'sys:UseMultipleStreamsWithinDrive' AND attrVal = 1
GROUP BY  id, componentNameId, attrName, attrVal
```

If this doesn't do what you want you will need to show exactly what output you need from your query.  Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Abe - I think I'm on track now. I was adding the MAX variable too early. I'll keep you posted as this is now generating the results I want. Thanks!